# How can I reopen chrome window?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

Unfortunately, I closed my chrome window which contains more than 20 tabs. Few of them have good information. Search for again all those pages it will take much time, few I forgot where I got those pages also.

Answer (score 0):

```
 To reopen recently closed chrome tabs/windows: 
 Press Ctrl (Command for mac users) + Shift + T 
 Note: It can reopen not only tabs, it can reopen recently closed windows also.
```